# How to play a video from url in android?

Tags: android

I have all my videos stored in server. I need to connect to that server and should display the video. I tried in all ways...searched in google...tried with many samples but still my video is not playing. It is displaying the message "Sorry cannot play this video". Please help me with this issue...struggling for this...

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below in your activity. Is this what you are looking for?

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.video);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
              Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g")));
```

Answer (score 0):

your videos should be in [format that is supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) by Android.